# Angular and Linear Motion

Tags: trigonometry

Albert Juarez's truck has wheels $36$ inches in diameter.  If the wheels are rotating at $360$ rpm (revolutions per minute), find the truck's speed in miles per hour.
This problem, it is said, can be solved in two ways:

1. using a form of the arc length formula
2. by a conversion factor that equates $1$ radian of angular measure to $1$ radius of arc length.

The answer given is $67.47$ miles/ hour.  But how you set up the arc length formula:  $V=RW$?

Comment: The answer given is 67.47 miles/hour.  The other was a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider a circle of radius $R$ that's rotating. After a singe rotation, we know the circle has moved for a distance equal to it's perimeter. So $x=2\pi R$. Now it is rotating with a certain angular frequency $\omega$, which means that it will rotate $\omega$ radians per second, or has $\omega/(2\pi)$ rotations per second (or $2\pi/\omega$ seconds per rotation). If we now look at the velocity we see:
$$V = \frac{x_{rotation}}{t_{rotation}} = \frac{2\pi R}{(2\pi)/\omega} =\frac{2\pi}{2\pi}R\omega = R\omega $$

Comment: Yes, this is something that went wrong while translating it to English. I'll change it. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

Rule of Three (Proportion)

In $1$  revolution the distance covered is $2πr = πd$, $r$ is radius, $d$ is diameter.

In $1$ minute there are $360$ revolutions.

1) In $1$ minute the distance covered is $360×πd$.

2) In $1$ hour the distance covered is $60×360×πd$.

Since $d$ is given in inches, convert to miles: $1.578×10^{-5}$ mile = $1$ inch.

Hence distance per hour covered in miles:

Distance = $60×360×πd×1.578×10^{-5}$  [miles]

Speed  = $60×360×πd×1.578 ×10^{-5}$ [miles/hour]

Comment: A mile is larger than an inch.  You meant $1~\text{in} = 1.578 \times 10^{-5}~\text{mile}$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig. Thanks.